# Python script insert data MySQL Google Cloud

Tags: python, mysql, database, google-app-engine

Good afternoon everyone, I'm learning about python and database.
I have a local MySQL "PHP my admin" database and two codes: 
1)inserts fixed values.
2)inserts variable values.
Then I have another MySQL google cloud database.
The code "1" runs fine in both DB. 
The code "2" works fine in local database but not in mysql google database. Connection seems to be done but log is not added.
Can somebody helps?

first one (fixed values):

```
import mysql.connector
import sys

host_db = "xxxxx"
local_db = "xxxxx"
usuario = "root"
contrasena = "xxxxx"

try:
    conexion_db = mysql.connector.connect(host=host_db,
                                         database=local_db,
                                         user=usuario,
                                         password=contrasena)

cursor = conexion_db.cursor()

add_log = ("INSERT INTO prueba1"
          "(id, presion) "
          "VALUES (NULL, '10')")

try:
        cursor.execute(add_log)
        conexion_db.commit()
        print("Guardando en base de datos...OK")
except:
        conexion_db.rollback()
        print("Guardando en base de datos...Falló")
```

the second script is pretty similar it changes add_log and cursor execute as follows:

```
valor = "500"

add_log = """INSERT INTO prueba1 
            (Id, presion) 
            VALUES (%s, %s) """

log = ("NULL", valor)

try:
        cursor.execute(add_log, log)
        conexion_db.commit()
```

Comment: `"NULL"` is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: Please let us know if the suggested change from Daniel worked for you